# Deploy Asp.Net Core and angular standalone template issue

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, proxy, web-deployment, visual-studio-2022

after having developed my application using the templates in Visual Studio 2022 I have deployed on IIS,
but from DevTools I notice that the call to the API does not point to the back-end but the url uses the root of the front-end,
as if it did not consider the settings of the proxy.conf.js file. What have I not considered regarding the development environment?
Thank you,

Paolo

Comment: I solved it by putting the url of the backend site in the "environment.prod.ts" file. Hi Paolo